# SQL Copy part of a column into a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've inherited a poorly set-up data source. Given the current data structure of:

```
PreAddress                                          City    County
12312 Osprey Drive NW Gig Harbor                    NULL    NULL
12312 Osprey Drive NW Gig Harbor                    NULL    NULL
3022 SW Bradford St Seattle                         NULL    NULL
3022 SW Bradford St Seattle                         NULL    NULL
4605 Prestwick Lane SE Olympia                      NULL    NULL
921 129th Street Court East Tacoma Auburn/Pierce    NULL    NULL
```

I need to tear the City names out of the PreAddress column, and dump it in the City column, so it looks like:

```
PreAddress                                          City                    County
12312 Osprey Drive NW                               Gig Harbor              NULL
12312 Osprey Drive NW                               Gig Harbor              NULL
3022 SW Bradford St                                 Seattle                 NULL
3022 SW Bradford St                                 Seattle                 NULL
4605 Prestwick Lane SE                              Olympia                 NULL
921 129th Street Court East                         Tacoma Auburn/Pierce    NULL
```

Any SQL Gurus out there have any idea how to script that?

**UPDATE**

First Pass SQL:

```
USE [SMS]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpCitiesCounties') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmpCitiesCounties
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpCityCleanup') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmpCityCleanup
GO

CREATE TABLE #tmpCitiesCounties
    ( [ccId] INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
                 PRIMARY KEY
    , [City] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , [County] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE #tmpCityCleanup
    ( [Id] INT NULL
    , [Address] VARCHAR(64) NULL
    , [City] VARCHAR(50) NULL
    , [County] VARCHAR(50) NULL );

INSERT  INTO [#tmpCitiesCounties]
        ( [City], [County] )
VALUES  ( 'Battle Ground', 'Clark' ),
        ( 'Camas', 'Clark' ),
        ( 'La Center', 'Clark' ),
        ( 'Ridgefield', 'Clark' ),
        ( 'Vancouver', 'Clark' ),
        ( 'Washougal', 'Clark' ),
        ( 'Yacolt', 'Clark' ),
        ( 'Fircrest', 'Pierce' ),
        ( 'Gig Harbor', 'Pierce' ),
        ( 'Unincorporated', 'Skagit' ),
        ( 'Arlington', 'Snohomish' ),
        ( 'Bothell/Snohomish', 'Snohomish' );

INSERT  INTO [#tmpCityCleanup]
        SELECT  [SNPR].[Id]
              , REPLACE(LOWER([SNPR].[PreAddress]), LOWER([TCC].[City]), '') AS [Address After]
              , [TCC].[City]
              , [TCC].[County]
        FROM    [dbo].[SellerNetProceedsResult] AS SNPR
                LEFT JOIN [#tmpCitiesCounties] AS TCC
                    ON [TCC].[City] = RIGHT(LOWER([SNPR].[PreAddress]), LEN(LOWER([TCC].[City])))
        ORDER BY [SNPR].[Id] DESC

SELECT  [TCC1].[Id]
      , [TCC1].[Address]
      , [TCC1].[City]
      , [TCC1].[County]
FROM    [#tmpCityCleanup] AS TCC1
```

So, this chunk of SQL correctly tears things out (that temp table of Cities and Counties is truncated, as there are a lot more than I wanted to put in this post), but as in the case of the row above where it has "Tacoma Auburn/Pierce", the SQL above leaves "Tacoma" after removing "Auburn/Pierce".

If I then run the following sql code, I get no recognition between the two tables on the address:

```
SELECT  [TCC1].*
      , REPLACE([TCC1].[Address], [TCC2].City, '') AS [Address After]
      --, [TCC2].[City]
      --, RIGHT([TCC1].[Address], LEN([TCC2].[City]))
FROM    [#tmpCityCleanup] AS TCC1
        left JOIN [#tmpCitiesCounties] AS TCC2
            ON [TCC2].[City] = RIGHT([TCC1].[Address], LEN([TCC2].[City]))
```

Instead, the "Address After" column is just null.

```
Id      PreAddress                              City            County  Address After
151     12312 osprey drive nw Gig Harbor        Algona          King    NULL
150     12312 osprey drive nw                   Gig Harbor      Pierce  NULL
```

Perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to have a lookup table of the possible table names. Off the top of my head, maybe something like:

```
UPDATE Address SET
  PreAddress=Replace(a.PreAddress,b.City,''),
  City=b.City
FROM Address a INNER JOIN Cities b  ON b.City=RIGHT(a.PreAddress,LEN(b.city))
```

Comment: This is actually not far off from what I had been thinking of doing. I had already generated the temp lookup table variable to use with the statement.

Comment: This method works great in a "first pass" run, but the second pass goes belly up for some reason. Still, I think this is the right path, and will do exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: What's the "second pass" of which you speak? Since you're updating the PreAddress field (and taking out the city), obviously it won't match any rows in the Cities table any more. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Well, the "first pass" goes great for instances where there's one city name repeatedly in the address... but when there are DIFFERENT towns, it all goes to hell. (that's sarcasm) I'll update the main post with the SQL I've used.

Comment: What if you use an INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN like in my example?

Comment: In your cities tables, do you have "Tacoma" AND "Tacoma Auburn/Pierce"? If so, you'll definitely run into problems. In that case, you'll need 2 city tables- one with "compound" names like "Tacoma Auburn/Pierce" and one with "simple" names like "Tacoma." Do one pass with the compound names, then a second pass with the simple names.

Comment: The issue actually turned out to be that there were unseen leading spaces in the stupid city names. :)

Comment: And no, no compound names - the compounding was purely from bad data storage and retrieval. This script cured the stored info, and changes to the application cured the storage and retrieval errors. Thanks bunches for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If this is a once off update as opposed to a regular fix-up, for an alternative to SQL you use a batch geocoding service that will format the address's, and you could load them back into the table.  You'd get co-ordinates that way too :).

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work

```
 DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (
        Adress VARCHAR(100),
        City VARCHAR(100), 
        County VARCHAR(1)
    )

    INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES ('12312 Osprey Drive NW Gig Harbor',NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES ('12312 Osprey Drive NW Gig Harbor', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES ('3022 SW Bradford St Seattle', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES ('3022 SW Bradford St Seattle', NULL, NULL)

    --Before Update
    SELECT LEFT(Adress, NULLIF(LEN(Adress)-7,-5)), REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Adress),1,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Adress))-1)),County  FROM @Tbl 
    --Something like this is what you need
    UPDATE @Tbl  
    SET Adress = t.Adress,
        City = t.city,
        County = t.county
    FROM @Tbl t 
    WHERE t.Adress = Adress
    AND t.City = City
```